# onUserInteraction method not enough for application timeout

Tags: android

I have an application which needs to log the user out after no activity is detected. I am using a timer that resets when the user interacts with the app. I have been using OnUserInteraction method; however this does not track interaction with the Soft Keyboard.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
    logoutTimer.RestartTimer();
}
```

My problem is that this application allows the user to input text (without limit) and the application times the user out in the middle of inputting text. Is there another way of listening for Keys being pressed on a softkeyboard? (I know I can create a listener on the editText but there are multiple editTexts on different fragments and was wondering if there is a better way)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to do this via onUserInteraction only. You can extend EditText, set a TextWatcher in it and catch all interactions with this EditText in TextWatcher's callbacks. Then you have to substitute this newly created EditText of yours in all places where you use to have standard EditText. I tried to override onKeyEvent() method inside the activity which hosts my EditText and refresh the timer in onKeyDown or onKeyUp, but to no avail. SoftInput seems to redirect all touches not to your activity, but to its own Window, that is why you won't see any keyEvents in activity.